How to calculate the average data across subdatasets in a SpatRasterDataset object in terra
I have a SpatRasterDataset:
library(terra)

r = rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   

s = terra::sds(r, r/2, r/3)

names(s) = letters[1:3]

It looks like:
> s
class       : SpatRasterDataset 
subdatasets : 3 
dimensions  : 77, 101 (nrow, ncol)
nlyr        : 3, 3, 3 
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
source(s)   : logo.tif, memory 
names       : a, b, c 

I want to calculate the average data across 3 SpatRaster in the SpatRasterDataset. The resulting data should be a SpatRaster with the same dimension as each SpatRaster in the SpatRasterDataset. This means I want to have a single SpatRaster with dimensions  : 77, 101 (nrow, ncol) where each cell value is the average of the corresponding cells in the three subdatasets.
What I have tried so far:
> terra::app(s, mean)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : logo 
names       :      red,    green,     blue 
min values  :   0.0000,   0.0000,   0.0000 
max values  : 155.8333, 155.8333, 155.8333 

but not what I expected.

Each SpatRaster in the SpatRasterDataset has 3 layers (nlyr: 3, 3, 3). So, should the result be a single SpatRaster with the averages for the first, second, and third layers of each SpatRaster? Or a SpatRaster with a single layer showing the average of all 9 layers?

result should also have 3 layers. thanks for pointing out :)

As Fernando pointed out in the comments, this works as expected (and is what you are after:
terra::app(s, mean)

To get the mean across datasets and layers you could do
rast(s) |> mean()


Simplifying:
r = rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
s3 <- c(r, r/2, r/3)
s3

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 9  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
sources     : logo.tif  (3 layers) 
              memory  (3 layers) 
              memory  (3 layers) 
colors RGB  : 1, 2, 3 
varnames    : logo 
              logo 
              logo 
names       : red, green, blue,   red, green,  blue, ... 
min values  :   0,     0,    0,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0, ... 
max values  : 255,   255,  255, 127.5, 127.5, 127.5, ...

s3_mean <- app(s3, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

s3_mean

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
source(s)   : memory
name        :     mean 
min value   :   0.0000 
max value   : 155.8333 
plot(s3_mean)

i.e., one very small change away from terra::sds to c(.

unfortunately, I have to use rast::sds() while reading my data (its a single .nc data). this example was shown for reproducibility

You can use c(s$a, s$b, s$d) to wrangle your sds to 9 lyr rast. Using d rather than c here. But this fails 3 lyr result desired, just mentioned.

yes, exactly. it is not what I am looking for. number of layers are time series data in my original example, and I need to have them in the final result

so you can <- app(s$a, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE, for s$a:d, then  <- c(a_mean, b_mean, d_mean), perhaps? Best to try on your data to see if results seem correct.
